# Unhashable type: 'list' error when running python script in mininet

Tags: python, network-programming, mininet

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.link import Link
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI

class myNetwork(Topo):
 "three users connected to cloud"

 def build(self, **_opts):
  #create switch
  s1 = \
  [ self.addSwitch for s in 's1' ]
  #create hosts
  h1, h2, h3 = \
  [ self.addHosts for h in 'h1', 'h2', 'h3' ]
  #create links
  [for h,s in [(h1,s1), (h2,s1), (h3,s1)]: self.addLink(h,s)

def run():  
 topo = myNetwork()
 net = Mininet(topo=topo)
 net.start()
 CLI(net)
 net.stop()

if __name__=='__main__':
setLogLevel('info')
run()
```

When I try to run my python script in mininet, I get the error:

Unhashable type: 'list'

I tried to research this, and I understand what the error means but I'm not sure why exactly I'm getting this error when I run my python script.

Comment: `self.addSwitch for s in 's1'` what??? if you don't master list comprehensions, then, don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're a little confused on how List Comprehensions work. You might be trying to do

```
[ self.addSwitch for s in s1 ] 
# notice the lack of quotes around s1, this means we want the VAR not the string
```

instead of

```
[ self.addSwitch for s in 's1' ]
```

Also, you might have forgotten to remove the `[` from this line as I don't think this is proper syntax:

```
[for h,s in [(h1,s1), (h2,s1), (h3,s1)]: self.addLink(h,s)
```

to:

```
for h,s in [(h1,s1), (h2,s1), (h3,s1)]: self.addLink(h,s)
```

Here are a few examples on list comprehension:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

l_modified = [i+1 for i in l] # [2, 3, 4, 5]

a = "String"
a_list = [c for c in a] # ["S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]

b = [c.upper() for c in "hello"] # ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"]
```